# Слово «простой». Его омонимичная форма, не являющаяся существительным

Tags: омонимы

Среди форм существительного ПРОСТОЙ есть те, которые указаны ниже. Какие из них имеют омонимичные формы, не являющиеся существительными? 
простой, простоя, простои, простоев, простою

Answer (score 1):

> *...простой, простоя, простои, простоев, простою*

.

Омонимичные формы в других частях речи имеют  формы именительно-винительного *(прост**о**й)* и дательного *(прост**о**ю)* существительного *прост**о**й:*

*прост**о**й* —  прил.  (форма им.-в. п., ед. ч., м. р. или форма тв. п., ед. ч.,  ж. р. прилагательного *прост**о**й*);

*прост**о**й* —  гл. (форма ед. ч. повелительного наклонения от гл. *просто**я**ть*);

*прост**о**ю* —  прил. (форма тв. п., ед. ч., ж. р. прилагательного *прост**о**й*); в современном языке такая форма употребляется редко (преимущественно в поэзии);

*просто**ю***  — гл. (форма ед. ч., буд. вр. от глагола *просто**я**ть*).

.

**Для справки:**

Бывают омонимы *лексические, грамматические, фонетические, графические*.

Слова, относящиеся к одной и той же части речи и совпадающие по звучанию и написанию, называются ***лексическими омонимами***.

Совпадающие в написании и произношении формы одного слова или разных слов называются *омоформами* (***грамматическими омонимами***).

Разные слова,  одинаково звучащие, но по-разному пишущиеся, называются *омофонами* (***фонетическими омонимами***).

Разные слова, одинаково пишущиеся,  но по-разному  звучащие, называются *омографами* (***графическими омонимами***).

*Источник:  Касаткин Л.Л. и др. "Краткий справочник по современному русскому языку", М.,  2010.*

Answer (score 0):

Простой (какой?) - им.п. муж.р.(простой ответ) или тв.п. ж.р. (была простой крестьянкой). Простою - разговорная форма того же

Comment: Простою - это глагол.

Comment: @behemothus 
А не могли бы вы указать ВСЕ слова, которые имеют омонимичные формы, не являющиеся существительными?

Comment: Из вашего списка? Больше таковых нету. Можно, конечно, увидеть просторечное деепричастие в "простоя" и даже в "простоев" (вместо простояв), но как-то не хочется нелитературными формами оперировать.

Comment: Кстати говоря, "проятою" - это не омоним, а омограф, ударение у форм разное.